# Quick and Dirty Image Registration Tool

Tags: computer-vision, image-registration

Given two images, e.g. two cats, is there a library that includes a "quick and dirty" way of telling by how much the two images differ regarding translation and rotation? Image registration is a big field and every application I run into seems to be tailored to medical scans and usually has certain domain specific caps on the transformation ranges. The tool I require should take two images as an input and return an angle of rotation and a translation vector, maybe even a confidence metric, it's that simple. (Most algorithms out there are heavy-duty and focus on minute details for alignment, the tool I'm looking for need not be as exact.)

Answer (score 0):

If it needs not be very precise, you can probably tweak the code from [PyImageSearch](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2020/08/31/image-alignment-and-registration-with-opencv/) to better suit your application.

If you know that the two images you are going to compare do contain the same object *(i.e., if there is no additional object recognition problem that comes before this step)*, then you can maybe try using the [ORB detector](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dc/dc3/tutorial_py_matcher.html) to find the good keypoints, and then estimate the homography using [ViSP](https://visp-doc.inria.fr/doxygen/visp-2.10.0/tutorial-homography.html)